# Иллюзия выпуклости объектов с помощью CSS

Tags: css, css3

[image: Фото]

Ребят, подскажите, как сделать такую так сказать выпуклость разделов? Там где новости , знакомства.

И как чтоб цвет находился внизу блока? То есть не на весь блок, а как-бы распыление шло.

Comment: там не выпуклость, а фоном - картинка с размазанным по вертикали цветом

Comment: А где эту картинку можно найти?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: как по мне это не очень красиво...Почитай про псевдо елемент hover.Мне кажеться он идеальный для меню и всего такого.

Answer (score 2):

Такой эффект получается с помощью вертикального градиента. Вот пример:

```css
.line {
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
    123
</div>
<div class="line">
    123
</div>
<div class="line">
    123
</div>
<div class="line">
    123
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.div {
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.div:after {
  content: '';
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(#cfe7fa 0%, #6393c1 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="div">

</div>
```

Это если нужно, чтоб фон был не на всю ширину блока. Если на этом фоне ещё должен быть контент то можно оформить отдельным блоком